# Intervention Imageで加工した画像を非同期でローカルにダウンロードしたい

Tags: laravel, ajax

ajaxでリクエストを送り、
バックエンドで「Intervention Image」を利用して画像を加工したものを
ローカルにダウンロードしたいのですが、
加工した画像データをblobに変換することができず詰まっておりました。

Intervention Imageにstreamで返却する関数などもあるとのことで
やってみてたのですが、
フロントに戻ってきた時点で文字化けしてしまいという状況でした。

どなたかお助けしていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

### javascript

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/export/img',
        data: {
            'img_type': imgType
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }).done((response) => {
        const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'image/png'});
        const filename = 'test.png'
        const downloadUrl  = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadUrl;
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
    }).fail(() => {
        $("#errorModal").modal("show");
    });
```

### backend(controller)

```php
public function export(Request $request)
    {
        // 画像生成処理
        $img = $this->service->createImg($request->img_type);
        return $img->stream('png')->__toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決できました！！

### javascript

```
function exportImg(imgType) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/export/img',
      data: {
        'img_type': imgType
      },
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  }).done((response) => {
      const base64 = response.encoded;
      a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = base64;
      a.download = dayjs().format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss") +".png";
      a.click();
      $("#spinner").css("display", "none");
  }).fail(() => {
      $("#errorModal").modal("show");
  });
}
```

### php

```
public function export(Request $request)
{
    // 画像生成処理
    $img = $this->service->createImg($request->img_type);
    return $img->encode('png')->encode('data-url');
}
```